# Select two elements of tuple given interval

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I have the following tuple:

```
my_list = (1000, 3000, 7000, 15000 ,79000)
```

For any given number I give to a `selected` variable, I want to return both the the value in the tuple minus the `interval` and the selected value. By interval I mean the delta/difference between the selected value and the prior one I want to output. See FAB's comment for further clarification. I'm talking about location/index when saying interval.

Let's say, for example:

```
selected = 79000
interval = 2
```

Expected output: (7000, 79000)

or

```
selected = 7000
interval = 1
```

Expected output: (3000, 7000)

Note that the order of the values in tehe expected output follows that of the values in the tuple. So never would a larger number be output before a smaller one.

The ouptput I expect both values to be in is either a tuple e.g. (3000, 15000) or a list [3000, 15000].

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "interval". With the values as shown in your list it's ambiguous. Maybe show another list with a wider spread of values and expected output.

Comment: Clarifired in text.

Comment: Please edit the question to show different values in my_list. As it stands your question makes no sense. Changing my_list to a tuple makes no difference as tuple and list subscripting are identical. Please show meaningful values. Also, what happens if the *selected* values isn't in the tuple?

Comment: Just a comment... you've put now (in the last edit at least) `790000` as the value in list and `selected = 79000` (missing a zero)... you will need to deal with error handling for cases like this :)

Comment: „I want to return both the the value in the tuple minus the interval“ I don’t understand this. The examples suggest that interval is just used to index the tuple. Do you want to subtract from the value (which?) or the tuple (how?)?

Comment: I think the problem is: Given a value (`selected`) from the list/tuple, find my index for that value and substract the `interval` to return the value at the new identified index (along with the initial value). that was my understanding anyways.

Comment: How should this behave if a) *selected* is not found in the list/tuple or b) the *interval* offset from the observed index is negative?

Comment: If interval offset is negative (I guess you mean it goes below the lowest value), and/or the other error you mentioned: just raise error message, it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better ways, but please see my approach below:

```py
def getInterval(myList: list, selected, interval) -> tuple:
    idxSelected = myList.index(selected)
    return (myList[idxSelected - interval], myList[idxSelected])

my_list = [*range(1, 15)]
selected = 4
interval = 3

print(getInterval(my_list, selected, interval))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = (1, 2, 3, 4 ,5)

selected = 5
interval = 2
selected_location = my_list.index(selected) #Here, 4

try:
    print([my_list[selected_location-interval], my_list[selected_location]]) #(3, 5)
except:
    print([my_list[selected_location], my_list[selected_location+interval]]) #Incase the selected variable is on index 1, then 1-2 would give -1, which is not the desired index
```

Comment: Made an edit to the post: instead of list, I actually have a tuple.

Comment: I mean, it won't make a difference, as long as you don't want to update `my_list`

Comment: @KillerRebooted 1-2 **will** work. That equates to -1 and hence the last item in the list/tuple

Comment: Yea, but it won't produce the desired output

Comment: @KillerRebooted I don't think we really know what's expected. The question makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: Thansk for all the inpput guys, I have upvoted, although, this does not particularly solve my problem. Instaed of using index, I need to use the number itself as the locator. See the edit in the question for clarity. Also provided clarity on what's expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

selected = 5
interval = 2
difference = selected-interval

if my_list.index(difference) < my_list.index(selected): #To check if the Difference Value comes before the Selected Value
    print(difference, selected)
else:
    print(selected, difference)
```

Comment: I'm getting:  `if block_points.index(difference) < block_points.index(selected_block):
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple`